Using Rust cargo in Visual Studio Cde. Error: Unable to execute: "sh" "-c" "../gmp-src/configure --enable-fat --disable-shared --with-pic"
I am very new to coding with Rust, so I might not understand many things yet. Among other crates, I have been trying to install the Symbolica crate to use in my project. Up to this point, there has not been any problem at all when installing all other crates. The way I have been doing so is by inputting name_of_crate = "version". When saving the file, the rust analyzer has been building automatically. But when I attempt to install Symbolica, it has been different. It gives me the following error:
ERROR rust_analyzer::main_loop: FetchBuildDataError:
error: failed to run custom build command for `gmp-mpfr-sys v1.6.2`
note: To improve backtraces for build dependencies, set the CARGO_PROFILE_DEV_BUILD_OVERRIDE_DEBUG=true environment variable to enable debug information generation.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\arki\Desktop\RUST-\MyRustApp\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-208c89227956b5a0\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GMP_MPFR_SYS_CACHE
  $ mkdir -p "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\lib"
  $ mkdir -p "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\include"
  $ rm -r "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\build"
  $ mkdir -p "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\build"
  $ ln -s "C:\\Users\\arki\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\gmp-mpfr-sys-1.6.2\\gmp-6.3.0-c" "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\build\\gmp-src"
  $ mkdir -p "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\build\\gmp-build"
  $ cd "C:\\Users\\arki\\Desktop\\RUST-\\MyRustApp\\target\\debug\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-6cd0651d19e463cc\\out\\build\\gmp-build"
  $ "sh" "-c" "../gmp-src/configure --enable-fat --disable-shared --with-pic"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\arki\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\gmp-mpfr-sys-1.6.2\build.rs:1207:29:
  Unable to execute: "sh" "-c" "../gmp-src/configure --enable-fat --disable-shared --with-pic"
  stack backtrace:
     0: rust_begin_unwind
               at /rustc/9b00956e56009bab2aa15d7bff10916599e3d6d6/library\std\src/panicking.rs:645:5
     1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
               at /rustc/9b00956e56009bab2aa15d7bff10916599e3d6d6/library\core\src/panicking.rs:72:14
     2: build_script_build::execute::{{closure}}
     3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap_or_else
     4: build_script_build::execute
     5: build_script_build::configure
     6: build_script_build::build_gmp
     7: build_script_build::compile_libs
     8: build_script_build::main
     9: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once

I have MSYS64 installed. I am using GCC.
If it helps, have previously stumbled upon an error when insalling Symbolica of not bing able to do symbolic link in a similar way, but I solved it by running Visual Studio Code as administrator.
I have searched everywhere but I don't seem to find anything specific to my error. Or if there is, I wouldn't know how to find it.

See install for windows in https://crates.io/crates/gmp-mpfr-sys

You can find the build script that is failing, by first looking up the gmp-mpfr-sys crate on crates.io and then going to its repository and looking at its build.rs. Relevant code excerpted from there:
fn execute(mut command: Command) {
    println!("$ {command:?}");
    let status = command
        .status()
// here comes your PANIC (line 1207):
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Unable to execute: {command:?}")); 
    if !status.success() {
        if let Some(code) = status.code() {
            panic!("Program failed with code {code}: {command:?}");
        } else {
            panic!("Program failed: {command:?}");
        }
    }
}

Looking at the stacktrace in your error, it came there via configure and build_gmp:
fn configure(build_dir: &Path, conf_line: &OsStr) {
    let mut conf = Command::new("sh");
    conf.current_dir(build_dir).arg("-c").arg(conf_line);
    execute(conf);
}

fn build_gmp(env: &Environment, lib: &Path, header: &Path) {
    let build_dir = env.build_dir.join("gmp-build");
    create_dir_or_panic(&build_dir);
    println!("$ cd {build_dir:?}");
    let mut conf = String::from("../gmp-src/configure --enable-fat --disable-shared --with-pic");
    if let Some(cross_target) = env.cross_target.as_ref() {
        conf.push_str(" --host ");
        conf.push_str(cross_target);
    }
    configure(&build_dir, &OsString::from(conf));
    make_and_check(env, &build_dir);
    let build_lib = build_dir.join(".libs").join("libgmp.a");
    copy_file_or_panic(&build_lib, lib);
    let build_header = build_dir.join("gmp.h");
    copy_file_or_panic(&build_header, header);
}

I have the impression that it simply cannot find sh to execute. You should probably try to manually change to the gmp build directory and try to run that sh command to verify.

sh will be the UNIX shell and the OP is running Windows.  It looks like the build.rs is not cross-platform.

I verified it, and turns out I had not included the git path to the sh command. Once I added it, it worked on starting its execution. But now I have a new problem with m4. Since it's not the same problem and I am new to stack overflow too, I'm not sure if I should edit this one to show the new error or form a new question. Regardless, I'll mark this as the solution!
